# Conversão decimal para hexadecimal

Tags: python, conversão, hexadecimal, decimal

Eu estou precisando fazer um algoritmo em python para fazer um conversor de decimal para hexadecimal. Mas não posso usar ifs e nem funções prontas, tipo hex(). Eu fiz, mas quando fui imprimir o valor em hexa eu usei o print("%X"%h) para imprimir as letras sem usar o if, mas percebi que isso converte qualquer numero em hexadecimal, mas isso seria uma função pronta e não é isso que eu quero. Existe uma maneira de fazer isso?
Meu código:

```
n = int(input())
r = []

while n > 0:
    r.append(n % 16)
    n = n // 16

for i in range(len(r)-1,-1,-1):
    print("%X"%r[i],end="")
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, por favor vá direto ao problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer assim :

```
hex = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","B","C","D","E","F"]
n = int(input("Digite um núemro inteiro: "))
r = []
while n > 0:
    r.append(hex[(n % 16)])
    n = n // 16
for i in range(len(r)-1,-1,-1):
    print(r[i],end="")
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/XpQD9v)

Comment: Massa! não estava conseguindo pensar em uma maneira de fazer a  conversão de decimal em hexadecimal sem usar o if, ou uma função pronta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Neste exemplo abaixo eu utilizei o doctest para validar os resultados.

```
def int2hex(n):
    '''
    :param n: int
    :return: str
    >>> int2hex(10)
    'A'
    >>> int2hex(15)
    'F'
    >>> int2hex(32)
    '20'
    >>> int2hex(255)
    'FF'
    >>> int2hex(65535)
    'FFFF'
    '''

    x16 = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f'.upper().split()
    result = []
    while n > 0:
        result.append(x16[(n % 16)])
        n = n // 16
    result.reverse()
    return ''.join(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

    print(int2hex(64202))
```

O trecho:

```
>>> int2hex(10)
'A'
```

São referentes as chamadas doctest, onde na primeira linha é a chamada do método e a segunda o resultado esperado.

Na linha:

```
x16 = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f'.upper().split()
```

Crio uma lista caixa alta com os valores hexadecimais.

No trecho:

```
while n > 0:
    result.append(x16[(n % 16)])
    n = n // 16
```

Decomponho o número de base 10 para base 16, entretanto é armazenado ao contrario.

Na linha:

```
result.reverse()
```

Inverto os valores armazenados na lista.

e por ultimo na linha:

```
return ''.join(result)
```

converto a lista em string e a retorno como resposta.

Como execução o trecho:

```
print(int2hex(64202))
```

apresenta como resultado **'FACA'**

Se for necessário a entrada dos valores no formato string, pode-se acrescentar um casting e também tratamento de excessões.

Exemplo completo:

```
def int2hex(n):
    '''
    :param n: int
    :return: str
    >>> int2hex(10)
    'A'
    >>> int2hex(15)
    'F'
    >>> int2hex(32)
    '20'
    >>> int2hex(255)
    'FF'
    >>> int2hex(65535)
    'FFFF'
    '''

    x16 = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f'.upper().split()
    result = []
    try:
        n = int(n)

        while n > 0:
            result.append(x16[(n % 16)])
            n = n // 16
        result.reverse()
    except ValueError as e:
        return ('Erro: %s' %e)
    except:
        raise
    else:
        return ''.join(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()


    print(int2hex(64202))
    print(int2hex('20'))
    print(int2hex('a'))
    print(int2hex('15'))
```